# SublimeText zoom only one pane not all

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When using SublimeText I have two monitors and I want to only zoom one of the two.

It seems that when I have two panes open I cannot have different zoom levels between them. Basically I want my larger monitor to be more zoomed in and my smaller laptop one to be less zoomed in.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this desired behavior?

I see https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami and https://github.com/jisaacks/MaxPane but they do not seem to do exactly what I'm wanting.

Comment: Why not just use two windows?

Comment: Even having two instances of SublimeText open if I zoom in on one the other zooms in too. I'm running SublimeText 3 on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the font size ("zoom level") of a particular view via the console, which is accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>. Just run:

```py
view.settings().set("font_size", 16)
```

for example to set that view's font size to 16. You can change the number to whatever you want. Keep in mind that this will only apply to the current view or tab, not any other tabs or panes in that window.

---

To apply the setting to every open file in a window, use [projects](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects). Create two projects (**`Project -> Save Project As...`**), one in each window. Determine the font size you want in each. Then, select **`Project -> Edit Project`** and add

```
"font_size": XX
```

to the `"settings"` section of the `.sublime-project` file, where `XX` is the font size you want. For example, `Big Monitor.sublime-project` might look like this:

```js
{
    "settings":
    {
        "font_size": 16
    }
}
```

while `Laptop Monitor.sublime-project` might look like this:

```js
{
    "settings":
    {
        "font_size": 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I needed.